# I am trying to deploy a flask application on pythonanywhere the first pages open but when I try to to the database i get an Internal server error

Tags: database, sqlite, deployment, flask-sqlalchemy, with-statement

Errors I am getting

[image]

my folders **init**.py file

[image]

[image]

I think the users data is not being submitted to the data base and the database path I think i have written it correctly, i don't know if there are some packages i failed to download

Comment: I think that is done when you are running the server on thel local machine

Comment: Check the flask sqlalchemy docs on how to specify the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI